# IIS5 or IIS6 Web Application running under IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, iis-5

I have a web application that runs fine under IIS5 or IIS6.  I just installed Vista, which has IIS7.  I just copied the entire web app over as-is, no changes to any files.  I went into the IIS7 manager and created a web appliction under the Default Web Site and pointed it to the app I copied over.

When I try to browse to the app in IE, it tells me there's nothing there to handle it and that directory browsing is not turned on.  This is a .NET app, so it uses Default.aspx.  I looked in the manager, and there was no handling of Default.aspx setup.  Is that not on by default for IIS7?

So, I added Default.aspx, and now the error is "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map."

I thought maybe it was because the default for IIS7 is Integrated Mode, so I created a new AppPool for Classic Mode and changed my app to use that.  I still get the same error.

I was under the impression that I could move .NET apps to IIS7 without any changes.  Is this not true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0) Check if you have asp.net extensions installed under Programs and Features - Windows Features - WWW services - Application Development Features - .Net Extensibility / ASP.Net

1) The Microsoft .net framework

2) Try copying the whole directory to your IIS's root folder (usually wwwroot), common error that iuser/iwam does not have rights to read the other folder.

3) Check under "Handler Settings" if you have .aspx associated with any Isapimodules.

Comment: 0) was it.  I thought I had gone into the Windows Features and turned everything on, but I missed .Net Extensibility / ASP.Net.  Thanks!

However, now I just get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" in IE and "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost" in FF.  I think it has something to do with my SSL setup...

Comment: Yep, it was my SSL setup.  With IIS 5 and 6, I used selfssl to create a self cert for the site, but with IIS 7, there's a place in the management UI to create the self cert, and then add a binding for it.  Everything is working great now.  Thanks again.